# How to fire appEvent after toastEvent in lightning controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, event, toast

I have an appEvent on a child controller to update a parent method after a toast. I have set an alert on the parent in the parent method to figure out if my event is working properly. My alert shows up before the toastEvent. How can I trigger my appEvent after the toastEvent.

Controller:

```
else {

            var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
            toastEvent.setParams({
                "title": "",
                "message": "Please fill all the required fields with the red asterisks",
                type:"error",
            });
            toastEvent.fire(); 

            var appEvent = $A.get("e.c:ContinueOrStop");                 
            appEvent.setParams({
                "currentStep" : "2" });                                
            appEvent.fire();
        }
```

Parent controller:

```
   var update = event.getParam("currentStep"); 

     if(update == "2" ){
         alert("MOVE")
         component.set("v.currentStep", "2");
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to simply listen to the toast event like you listen to any other event and chain your actions.

```
<aura:handler event="force:showToast" action="{!c.handleApplicationEvent}"/>
```